# What's the Drupal function to display image src?

Tags: php, image, drupal-7

I have an HTML file and some images. While theming, I have used the function `drupal_get_path` to display the images, but none of them are showing. I have already tried the code below. If anyone could help, it would be a great help.

```
<?php echo drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME'); ?>/images/slider/slide1_baner1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $GLOBALS['theme'] for get the current theme's path (Optional).

Use theme_image to get the html of an image.

The Drupal way for resolving this problem would be something like this:

```
$variables = array(
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME').'/images/slider/slide1_baner1.jpg',
  'alt' => 'Alt of image',
  'title' => 'Image title',
  'width' => '50%',
  'height' => '50%',
  'attributes' => array('class' => 'img-class', 'id' => 'banner1'),
);
$output = theme('image', $variables );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below way!
`<?php
global $theme; // Returns the current active theme name.
?>
<img"<?php echo drupal_get_path('theme', $theme); ?>/images/slider/slide1_baner1.jpg" alt="" />`

Just try once to debug that what the `drupal_get_path()` returns. May be for you, it's not returning the exact browse-able path and that's why the images are not coming.

Keep Drupalizing :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a similar question on Drupal Answers: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121488/whats-the-correct-relative-path-to-a-local-image.

You can use the code

```
<?php global $base_url; ?>     

<img src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/all/themes/MY-THEME/images/slider/slide1_baner1.jpg">
```

or the function `file_create_url`.